# Android, How to define multiple variables at once

Tags: java, android

I have two variables and was wondering how I would define both at once.

```
    Button answer1;
Button answer2;
```

Comment: by doing exactly what you just did?

Comment: But if I have dozens is there not a shorter way?

Comment: In the future, questions about Java syntax should be put in the `java` tag. The `android` tag should be for Android-specific questions. If you are worried that something about Android might affect the Java syntax, feel free to tag with both tags.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks and noted. Would have made more sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to do this:

Button answer1, answer2;

Answer (score 1):

This seems like it should be correct.

```
Button answer1, answer2;
```